# Low level caching in rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I have two models Employee and Organization

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, touch: true
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
```

There is a form which is used to search the employees.

The search query is based on first_name, last_name and emp_id.

I am trying to implement **Low-Level Caching**

In Employee Controller

```
def list_employees
  first_name = params[:employee][:first_name]
  last_name  = params[:employee][:last_name]
  emp_id     = params[:employee][:emp_id]
  @employees = Employee.all_employees(first_name,last_name,emp_id)
end
```

In Employee Model

```
def self.all_employees(first_name,last_name,emp_id)
  cache_key = "#{first_name}-#{last_name}-#{emp_id}"
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}", expires_in: 5.minutes) do
    Employee.where("first_name like ? and last_name like ? and emp_id like ?","%#{first_name}%","%#{last_name}%","%#{emp_id}%")
  end
end
```

But i cant see any difference each time its querying again. I can see data
Rails.cache.fetch("cache_keys") from console even here its querying to employee table.

First time when i query it takes 500ms
Second time same query it takes  490ms (not serving from cache)

Let me know what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really have `emp-id` in the code? If this is not your actual code, then you might have missed crucial details when simplifying it for the question

Comment: Would it make a difference if you do `Employee.where("first_name like ? and last_name like ? and emp_id like ?","%#{first_name}%","%#{last_name}%","%#{number}%").to_a` in the fetch call? Notice the trailing `.to_a`

Comment: While framing question i missed it, i have corrected emp_id.  
I will try .to_a, but my confusion why caching is not working

Comment: I'm suspecting that you actually don't store the data there. Only the query.

Comment: i added .to_a and checked from console its faster, they have not mentioned anywhere in rails doc thank you.  can you please explain me what it does, also i have pagination which wont work on array

Comment: According to me, if cache key matches it gives output of query without any load. which did when i gave .to_a. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: Not sure I understand what you said in the last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you store as your cached value:

```
Employee.where("first_name like ? and last_name like ? and emp_id like ?","%#{first_name}%","%#{last_name}%","%#{emp_id}%")
```

This is not a list of employees, this is only **information on how to find** the employees. So when you later retrieve this object from the cache, you run the query every time, to get the employees.

Run the query when caching, by appending `.to_a` to that. This will return an array of employees, which is what you want to cache.

Comment: Thank you. I am converting to .to_a, is there a chance of facing memory issue, as i am not using any cach_store.

Comment: Yes, if you're storing the cache in-memory, then you have a risk of memory bloat.

Comment: Can you suggest some as am very new to this. I am going to store it for 12 hours